# How to debug IPsec L2TP authentication failure (Ubuntu StrongSwan client to Windows Server 2012)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2012, ipsec, l2tp, strongswan

I'm trying to connect via IPsec L2TP to a Windows Server 2012 server. Both the clients and the host are behind a NAT.

I can connect from a Windows 7 machine without any problems, but when trying to connect using the same password from an Ubuntu 14.10 machine running StrongSwan I receive an `AUTHENTICATION FAILED` error message.

Having administrator access to the server and the client, where can I find more information about what is causing the authentication failure?

Given that the password is definitely correct, what other factors could cause an authentication error (rather than other sorts of connection errors)?

Comment: Did you use the IP-Sec-plugin for Networkmanager or the standalone software?

Comment: It's using standalone StrongSwan. I'm doing everything on the Ubuntu side via the command line.

Comment: Are you including the domain name of the Windows user in the username field, or is there a separate field for the domain on the Ubuntu box?

Comment: @CyberJacob, I have not been given a domain as part of my credentials, so I'm not entering a domain anywhere during login. From a Windows 7 client I can log in fine with no domain so I don't think that's part of the problem. Really I'd like to know how to view detailed logs/debugging info on the Windows server so I can see what its problem is.

Comment: Please follow the below youtube link for strongswan setup:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-Esrw8wxA4